# youtube player plugin with event when video ends

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

is there a `jquery plugin` to play `youtube videos` and to do something when video ends
i found some plugins, but can't make it to do something (ex: `alert()`; ) when video ends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you're using the Youtube JS Api, there should be a listener for the ***[onStateChange](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/js_api_reference.html#Adding_event_listener)*** event. When a video ends the status is 0, you could use this status to do something when the video ends.

**BTW**: this is why I don't like JQuery, developers are becoming more dependent on someone else's code.. and the eternal search for plugins that have all the functionalities that we need [just complaining to myself XD]